# How to put non existing value of a time series DataFrame at 0

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, plotly

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
```

```
df
          time             Feature_1   
1  03/01/2022 08:32:00       4562.2       
2  03/01/2022 08:32:11       4578.3       
3  03/01/2022 08:32:22       4602.4
4  03/01/2022 08:32:33       4567.3 
5  03/01/2022 08:32:44       4702.9
6  03/01/2022 08:32:55       4756.4
7  07/01/2022 16:32:00       4006.7
8  07/01/2022 16:32:11       4025.8
9  08/01/2022 08:30:00       5789.1
10 08/01/2022 08:30:11       5794.3
11 08/01/2022 08:30:22       4893.4
```

I'm using `plotly` :

```py
fig = px.line(df.reset_index(), x='time', y='Feature_1', title='Pressure')
#slider
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible = True,
)
fig.update_layout(title_text='Pressure', title_x=0.5)
fig.update_xaxes(
        tickangle = 0,
        title_text = "Date",
        title_font = {"size": 15},
        title_standoff = 10)
fig.update_yaxes(
        tickangle = 0,
        title_text = "Pression",
        title_font = {"size": 15},
        title_standoff = 10)
fig.show()
```

Between index 6 and 7, 3 days are missing, and between index 8 and 9, 16 hours are missing. When I plot my DataFrame, there is a line that connects the value of `feature_1` at index 6 to the value at index 7, and the value at  index 8 to the value at index 9.

How am I supposed to put all value between 2 non speciafied timestamp at 0?

I thought I could `resample` my DataFrame cause the main goal is to forecast my time series. But the problem is that I want to keep the time delta at 11secondes, which is ok for the first 6 index, but it will modify the following indexes.

Comment: It says 11 seconds apart, but it starts at 00 seconds, and in between are 11 seconds apart but at 00 seconds. Would you prefer an irregular interval?

Comment: @r-beginners , thats the main issue here, i cant have a regular interval without changing my timestamp right? Let's admit I want to resample with  11 seconds time delta, how can I fill new row with 0?

Comment: I wanted to ask, do all time series, including blank periods, need to have second intervals of [00,11,22,33,44,55]?

Comment: Have you considered converting `time` column to datetime?

Comment: `[0,11,22,33,44,55]` For this second interval, we would create a date range with a 10-second interval and prepare an answer that adds seconds with a time delta.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but this is my attempt.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

# Create range from min date to max date in df
range = pd.date_range(start=str(df['Time'].dt.date.min()), end=str(df['Time'].dt.date.max()))

# Get dates excluded in df and put in a list
dates_excl = range.difference(df['Time'].dt.date)
lstday_excl = list(dates_excl)

missing_dates = {'Time': lstday_excl, 'Feature_1': 0}

# Append missing dates to df
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(missing_dates))

# Sort df by Time to get data in order
df = df.sort_values(by = 'Time')
df
```

This was my output:

```
                 Time  Feature_1
0  2022-01-03 08:32:00     4562.2
1  2022-01-03 08:32:11     4578.3
2  2022-01-03 08:32:22     4602.4
3  2022-01-03 08:32:33     4567.3
4  2022-01-03 08:32:44     4702.9
5  2022-01-03 08:32:55     4756.4
0  2022-01-04 00:00:00        0.0
1  2022-01-05 00:00:00        0.0
2  2022-01-06 00:00:00        0.0
6  2022-01-07 16:32:00     4006.7
7  2022-01-07 16:32:11     4025.8
8  2022-01-08 08:30:00     5789.1
9  2022-01-08 08:30:11     5794.3
10 2022-01-08 08:30:22     4893.4
```